# Jquery/Ajax .load() randomly not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been using the Jquery .load function to request elements from a php file and display it on the page. At first I solely requested elements from first.php and everything loaded perfectly on-load. I then created a second function to request elements from second.php which causes the elements from first.php to not load sometimes (first.php should always displays elements) while second.php loads every time. For some reason loading first.php and then going back to this file makes it load properly again.

```
attempts = 0;


$(document).ready(function(){
roll_info();
past_rolls();
});

function roll_info(){
   $("#info").load("first.php", timer);
   //to see how many times the function is called 
   attempts++;
 }); 
}

function past_rolls(){
  $("#prevRolls").load("second.php");
}

//called after roll_info()
function timer(){
 //If the element requested by the ajax isn't added to the page it attempts to add again
 if (!document.getElementById("roll_info"))
 {
 roll_info();
 }

 //Refreshes roll_info() every 10 seconds if loaded successfully until no longer waiting
 else if (document.getElementById("status").innerHTML == "Status: Waiting..."){
   nextRefresh = setInterval(function(){
      roll_info();
      clearInterval(nextRefresh);
      return;},10000);
 }
 //other code
```

Looking in console at the value of "attempts" shows a number 1000+ right after loading which means that it's made thousands of failed requests through ajax? There are also no visible errors in console.

Any idea what's causing this inconsistency?

Comment: why are you wrapping `$(document).ready()` in another function? you should only have one `$(document).ready()` function and it should wrap the jQuery code that references DOM elements, also when/how are you calling `page_load()`?

Comment: Also can you explain what this check is for `if (!document.getElementById("roll_info"))`?

Comment: @koala_dev I fixed the document.ready() issue (first day using jquery lol) - Hopefully that was the issue. And the if (!document.getElementById("roll_info")) checks to see if one of the elements from first.php has been added to the page. If it isn't it keeps on calling roll_info until it works (which is never once it doesn't load in the first place).

Comment: So you want to check when the load() call is complete? if so then set up a callback function, check the docs for `load()` you shouldn't start multiple requests

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when *first.php* or *second.php* is loaded, provide a callback function to  `.load`.

Example from [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/load/) website:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

Just replace ajax/test.html with first/second.php.

BTW you should not be using setInterval to check if a file has loaded.